# Having trouble with multiplication table generator in C++

Tags: c++

So I made this program in C++ in which the user is prompted to enter a number and a multiplication table is generated based on the number that is inputted. It will continuously ask the user to input a number until an alphabet letter is pressed to quit.

I'm trying to make the table go up to 10, as it only goes up to 9. When you try to enter 10, it only generates a 1 x 1 table then the program closes. Also, I'm trying to make it so that when you enter a negative number such as -3, it displays something like "Number must be greater than 0" then the program continues to ask for a number input.

Here is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char userSelection;
    int numForTable;
    int col;
    int row;

    cout << "Please enter a number (press q or any letter to quit) ";
    while(cin>>userSelection)
    {
        int numForTable = (int)userSelection - 48;

        if(numForTable<1 or numForTable > 12)
        {
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout<<"Have a nice day"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "\n"
             << "Multiplication table for: " << numForTable << " is:" << endl
             << "\n"
             << "    " << 1;

            for (col = 2; col <= numForTable; ++col)

                cout << "    " << col;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "   ----|";


            for (col = 2; col <= numForTable; ++col)

                cout << "----|";
                cout << endl;


            for (col = 1; col <= numForTable; ++col)
            {
                cout << setw(2) << col << "|";

                for (row = 1; row <= numForTable; ++row)

                    cout << setw(4) << col * row << "|";
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << " -|----";

                for (row = 2; row <= numForTable - 1; ++row)

                    cout << "|----";
                    cout << "|----|";
                    cout << endl;
            }
        }
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a number (press q or any letter to quit) ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading a single character:

```
while(cin>>userSelection)
```

And then converting it to its numeric value:

```
int numForTable = (int)userSelection - 48;
```

The behaviour you're looking for would be better served by"

```
cin >> numForTable;
```

And choosing a different sentinel. Alternatively, read a full line of input and then extract the number from that string after checking for the `q`.